# How do I calculate the probability of sampling all samples from a list?

Tags: r, simulation, probability, sampling

I have a set amount of samples. I want to estimate how big a sample size I need (lack of terminology?), to at least pick all samples once by a specific probability, when the samples are replaced.

I am fairly new to R. But I think what I have to do is work with the sample function, but was also trying to do it by Monte Carlo simulation, but couldn't wrap my head around it.

I tried something like this:

```
sampling_prob = function(idnumber, probability_de){
sample(1:idnumber, sampling_number, replace = TRUE) 
MISSING CODE
}
sampling_prob(2200,0.99)
> 200000 ##This is not the correct number, but a very far-fetched guess
```

Thus, I want to estimate my needed sample size/sampling_number based on simulations.

Comment: Do you mean, when picking with replacement from a set of n items, how many samples are required for x probability of having picked all samples? (When n and x are given)

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30483/probability-of-selecting-each-item-at-least-once-when-sampling-with-replacement

Comment: Thanks Anotherfred!